# Unable to connect to remote mysql server using unixodbc, libmyodbc

Tags: mysql, odbc, unixodbc

I'm a little green at this, and I hope the issue I'm having is a simple one...edit: new information at bottom

I need to make a connection to a remote mysql (Amazon RDS) database.

After following a few tutorials, I have unixodbc and libmyodbc installed and configured on the client, but when I try to connect via isql, I get the error

```
[08S01][unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

The most confusing part about this error is that I'm not trying to connect to a local database, but rather to a remote one. I do not have a mysql.sock file on the client...this isn't the issue though is it?

I'm sensing a configuration error but I'm just not sure what it could be.

If I run odbcinst -j then the output is:

```
DRIVERS............: /etc/unixODBC/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/unixODBC/odbc.ini
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
```

The content of /etc/unixODBC/odbcinst.ini is:

```
[MySQL]
Description             = ODBC for MySQL
Driver          = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup           = /usr/lib64/unixODBC/libodbcmyS.so
UsageCount              = 5

[MySQL ODBC 515 Driver]
Description             = ODBC 5.515 for MySQL
DRIVER          = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5-5.1.5.so
SETUP           = /usr/lib64/unixODBC/libodbcmyS.so
UsageCount              = 3
```

Please note that I had to make up this configuration myself, I did a find for libmyodbc* and found these two .so files, thus set up a driver for each of them. A search for libodbcmyS* yields:

```
/usr/lib64/unixODBC/libodbcmyS.so.1
/usr/lib64/unixODBC/libodbcmyS.so
/usr/lib64/unixODBC/libodbcmyS.so.1.0.0
```

So, I don't know what else that configuration could be.

The content of /etc/unixODBC/odbc.ini is:

```
[target_db]
Driver          = MySQL
Server          = [servername.com]
Port            = 3306
Database        = [databasename]
Option          = 2
User            = [username]
Password        = [password]
```

I've tried different options in "Driver", changing it from MySQL, to MySQL ODBC 515 Driver, to the path to the .so file (eg: /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so) and all yield the same result.

I'm running:

```
odbcinst -i -d -f /etc/unixODBC/odbcinst.ini
```

Followed by:

```
odbcinst -i -s -l -f /etc/unixODBC/odbc.ini
```

Followed by:

```
odbcinst -s -q
```

Which prints out the name of my connection, ie [target_db]

Then, I try the connect:

```
isql -v target_db user password
```

or just

```
isql -v target_db
```

and get the error shown above.

Anyone happen to know what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks a bunch-

EDIT:

Wanted to mention that I'm able to connect to the database from this server using the mysql command line tools.

I installed a local mysql database, and I'm able to connect to this using isql. It seems to be ignoring my odbc.ini file entirely, i have to enter a name with the command, ie isql -v test-database, but it still tries to connect to localhost despite my settings.

I feel as though I've tried everything but will keep at it and will post if i find a solution.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue too, only on SLES 11.3 though, CentOS 6.4 is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to connect using the ip of your server instead of the dns entry on the "Server" line of odbc.ini.. Have you verified the driver is installed with phpinfo()?

Comment: This was my first idea too, but I'm seeing the same issue on SLES 11.3 (CentOS 6.4 works fine) and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the environment variable `ODBCINI` with the path of your odbc.ini file.

Keep in mind that the odbc.ini file you point to must be "write-accessible"  by the user that is running the program (i.e. the user must have permissions to write in this file).

Answer (score 0):

chmod g+w .odbc.ini did it for me since we run the DB with ORACLE-Start and the crs-User seems to be in charge