# Setup a linked server connection from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to a MySQL Amazon Web Services MySQL RDS?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, linked-server, rds

I want to add a MySQL instances that is running as a RDS service through Amazon Web Services as a Linked Server in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Does anyone know of any information on how I can set this up?

What I want to be able to do is query data from my MySQL server from the local Micorsoft SQL server and then combine the data into other queries.

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(MySQL_Link, 'SELECT * 
                FROM users
                WHERE name = 'test')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have the ODBC connection set up to connect to the instance?
[Unable to connect to remote mysql server using unixodbc, libmyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995987/unable-to-connect-to-remote-mysql-server-using-unixodbc-libmyodbc)

I would think that once you have that working, you would be able to use the same process for [creating a linked server to MySQL](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic340912-146-1.aspx)

I hope this is helpful.